# Is there a more formal way to the expression "Telling it like it is"?

Tags: synonyms, phrasing

I'm rewriting a guideline of professional conduct for my small company. One of the points mentioned requires managers to

> Tell it like it is: don't argue that a routine (but necessary) task is beneficial to your team's professional knowledge/ value to convince them of doing it. Instead, publicly acknowledge that there're more important tasks yet these routine ones are necessary.

I realize that "Tell it like it is" is a bit informal. Is there an alternate word/ phrase to it?

Comment: "Be blunt" is about as close to being blunt as you can get.

Comment: The extended description doesn't look like *telling it like it is*. Consider discarding the heading altogether and just start with "don't argue that ...".

Comment: How about "Explain the assigned tasks bluntly" and go on from there?

Comment: For cutting to the chase, 'Address the main point'. 'Not major on minors'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Tell it like it is](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell-it-like-it-is)***, is idiomatic and creates a bonding between management and its employees. It's plain simple talk, which people usually appreciate, so the OP could leave it. However, if a more "formal" approach is needed, I'd suggest the following: *Be concise and to the point*, and

> **Be honest and direct**, do not waste time arguing that a routine task is beneficial to your team's professional knowledge/ value. Instead, acknowledge these routine tasks as being dull but absolutely necessary.